# How to use read preferences in mongoskin?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-replication, mongoskin

Is there any way to define read prefence in mongoskin in collection or db level here is the sample from mongodb native nodejs driver
    http://learnmongodbthehardway.com/ex22.html

```
var readMongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;  

MongoClient.connect('localhost:3000/tes?readPreference=secondaryPreferred' , 

   function(err ,db){
        db.collection("sites").findOne(
        {
            $or: [{'a' : e}, 
                    {'a' : d},
                    {'a' : c},
                    {'a' : b}]
        }, function(error, result1){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                callback(null, result1)
                db.close();
            }       
        });
});

}
```

I am currently running mongos over a set of sharding server with replica sets. I need to route all the read query to secondary members of replica sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally there is way to route your query to secondary mongod

Just place the host and port of your secondary inside the mongoskin connection string like this

---

```
var mongo = require("mongoskin");
var database = mongo.db( "mongod://username:password@secondaryDatabasehost:port/database",{safe:true , slaveOk : true});
```

The **slaveOk:true** will allow secondary mongod to use for read only queries.Without this mongo wont allow to query from a secondary and gives you an error.

```
[Mongo error "$err" : "not master" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes.

Look here：

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_1and2_2.html#read-preferences